# JBOSS FUSE CORBA Proxy

Tags: apache-camel, corba, fuseesb

We are using `JBOSS FUSE 6.0.0` and program it using Apache Camel routes.A new requirement has come to Proxy a `CORBA` service as below:

```
System 1 ---> sends CORBA Request to--> JBOSS Fuse <BR>
JBOSS FuseFuse -->Transforms to SOAP HTTP--> System 2 <BR>
System2 -->Responds in SOAP HTTP---? JBOSS Fuse <BR>
JBOSS Fuse -->Converts SOAP to CORBA --> System 1. <BR>
```

Just needed your advise ,does anybody tried to use `JBOSS Fuse/ Apache Camel` as a `CORBA` Service consumer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current we don't have camel-corba component to access or provide the CORBA service.
If you still want to use camel you may need to let the CORAB implementation use the Camel [ProducerTemplate API](http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html) to send the message to the CamelContext.